# How to ignore certain fields for deserialization without jackson annotations?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class inside a spring framework project. The class must not be annotated with jackson. But, it is annotated with @Component i.e. org.springframework.stereotype.Component.

Class

```
@Component
public class SampleClass{
    String prop1;
    String prop2;
    String prop3;
    //Getters & Setters.
}
```

Json

```
"SampleClassJson" : {
    String prop1;
    String prop2;
}
```

As you can see, SampleClassJson does not have prop3. I want to create a SampleClass object which does not have the prop3 field, by using jackson. I don't want to create another class just for one missing field. How do I achieve this ? I could not find any answers by using google or by looking at object mapper settings.

Comment: *The class must not be annotated with jackson* - would you build a house without a hammer?

Comment: use `@JsonIgnore` on the getter method of that property you want to be ignored by jackson.

Comment: It would be good to know more context to this question to find better solutions. At the first glance, it doesn't make sense for something to be serialized to be annotated as @Component. Components are singletons and spring beans, both of which are definitely not properties of DTOs, which is what json serialization implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

Use `@JsonIgnore` on getter or field

**`Sample` class with `@JsonIgnore` annotation:**

```
class Sample {
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    @JsonIgnore // could be here
    private String prop3;

    @JsonIgnore // could be here
    public String getProp3() {
        return prop3;
    }
}
```

**`ObjectMapper` use annotations from the `Sample` class:**

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new Sample("one", "two", "three"))
```

Second variant, is to use custom serializer:

**Custom serializer:**

```
class SampleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Sample> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Sample sample, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("prop1", sample.getProp1());
        jgen.writeStringField("prop2", sample.getProp2());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

**Add annotation to use custom serializer:**

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SampleSerializer.class)
class Sample {

    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    private String prop3;
}
```

**`ObjectMapper` use annotations from the `Sample` class:**

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new Sample("one", "two", "three"))
```

If you do not use Jackson annotations for the class at all, you could add your custom serializer to `ObjectMapper`:

**`Sample` class does not contain any Jackson annotation:**

```
class Sample {

    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    private String prop3;
}
```

**`ObjectMapper` should know about the way how to serialize `Sample` class:**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Sample.class, new SampleSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

mapper.writeValueAsString(new Sample("one", "two", "three"));
```

Comment: *or use your custom serializer* I guess that is what he is after

Comment: @ScaryWombat What do you mean?

Comment: It means that your code was not showing the *custom serializer* when I commented

Comment: Yep, that was a draft version.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik - Thank you for the detailed reply. When we have, say 15 fields and only 2 are to be excluded for serialization, then its easier to say exclude 2 instead of saying include 13 in our custom serializer. I was wondering if we can tell JsonSerializer.serialize(abc) to serialize all fields except a given list of fields.

Comment: Yes, Exclude only with annotation. With custom serializer - you have to write all 13 values then. PS - actually there is one way, but this is quite hard, not standard and lots of code.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik - could you please tell me what that harder approach is ? I will google it to learn more. Thanks.